Using `perf` on the host machine, the symbols of the processes in the container cannot be displayed
My goal is to use perf record on the host machine to collect the hot symbols of all processes, including those in the container.
But I found that the symbol column of the process in the container only has the address. I tried to copy the binary in the container to the host machine, keeping the directory consistent, so that the symbols can be seen. So the problem seems to be that the perf tool cannot correctly identify the binary path in the container.
Is there a solution to this problem? Because it seems unrealistic to copy all the process binaries in the container to the host machine.
